# Semantic UI css messing with min-width property. How do I fix?

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I am trying to use the css min-width property for a div wrapper, however, using Semantic UI seems to hide the horizontal scrollbar.

By removing the link tag in the CodePen below reveals the problem with Semantic UI.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNjQMV)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css"/>
<div id="wrapper"></div>


#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #ff0000;
  min-width: 2500px;
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

Any idea on how I can fix this problem while still using Semantic UI?

Comment: It seems Semantic has the body css property overflow-x: hidden;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your concrete case semantics adds `overflow-x: hidden` to `<body>`.

Just add CSS:

```
body {
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyaQXM